# Print dialog does not have double-sided

Tags: printing, duplex-printing

I have a network printer which supports double-sided printing

```
> lpoptions -p printer-name -l | grep Du                                                                                              
HPOption_Duplexer/Duplex Unit: *True False
Duplex/2-Sided Printing: None *DuplexNoTumble DuplexTumble
```

and I am able to print double-sided by passing the correct options

```
> lp -d "printer-name" -n 1 -o portrait -o media=a4 -o sides=two-sided-long-edge ~/Downloads/mypdf.pdf
```

However, the print dialogs on my system (for example in Evince or Firefox) do not show the double-sided option for this particular printer (the option is shown correctly for other printers).
Where does the print dialog get its options? Is there a way to force showing the double-sided?

```
> lpstat -t | grep printer-name
device for printer-name: socket://printer-name
cps1cm3 accepting requests since Tue 18 Jan 2022 11:58:31 GMT
printer printer-name now printing printer-name-0.  enabled since Tue 18 Jan 2022 11:58:31 GMT
```

Comment: Printer model? Ubuntu version? Print dialogs showing this behaviour? Outputs of `lpstat -t` and `lpstat -l -e` please.

Comment: I am not sure what the printer model, but I think the printer is not the issue since `lp` prints correctly as expected. I have Ubuntu 20.04.3. I added the output of `lpstat`. The second command shows `lpstat: Error - unknown option "e"`. All print dialogs on my system are not showing the duplex printing option

Comment: e should be -e. The printer itself may not be the issue, but it would have been useful to know whether it is  IPP-capable or whether it is being advertised by a CUPS server. Is cups-browsed running?